# can webpart connections use parameters with less than and greater than - SP 2010

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

Is there a i can use webpart connections(parameters) in SP designer 2010
like this stardateparam <= paramdate => enddate param 
or i would have to use Querystring params?
Also does the date have to be in a specific format?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

yes, if I'm understanding what youre wanting to do. You will want to set your parameter and then use a 'start another workflow'. so, for example: if status = complete then start another workflow

Comment: ironman i don't think you really understand what i'm trying to do.I would like to use wepbart connections to do this
stardateparam <= paramdate => enddateparam 
Cheers